# current time = UTC +/- (UTC +/- current time in zone)

Tags: c++, timezone, strftime

I'm working on fixing an issue,to prevent the time zone specified using its acronym and instead use the 4-digit offset format to be represented.( UTC-6 for CST).
How could that be represented with the strftime(parameters)??

Answer (score 0):

`UTC%z` is pretty close to what you are asking for. For instance, that gives "UTC-0600" for me. I don't think you can do any better with strftime, but you could always modify the result of `%z` yourself.

Comment: how could the value of %z be modified?

Comment: @user1438138 Run strftime with %z: the result will be a string like "-0600". Now take that string and manipulate it however you want (for example, you could chop off the last two zeros).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just using `%z` directly and forget the "UTC-6" format. That format doesn't lend itself well to time zones with sub-hour offsets. For example, how would you represent an offset of 4:30? It's best to not invent another offset format if you can use a standard one that already exists.